# How do I select parameters in a KRL webhook?

Tags: krl, webhooks

I want to run some KRL rules when a website is updated. The deploy script will get the following URL after pushing the updates:

```
http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/_appid_/updated?site=production&version=123456abcdef
```

The ruleset to handle this webhook starts out like this:

```
rule site_updated {
    select when webhook updated
    pre {
        site = event:param("site");
        version = event:param("version");
    }
    // do something with site and version
}
```

From http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Event_API I could make more specific rules with:

```
select when webhook updated site "test"
    or webhook updated site "production"
```

Is there a way to get both parameters without a PRE block? What is the best way to use SELECT with a webhook?

Comment: Your `/update` in the URL and the `select when webhook updated` don't match, but I think you intended them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule filters (like `site "test"`) are regular expressions, and you can set variables using the `setting ()` clause.

```
http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/_appid_/update?site=production&version=123456abcdef

select when webhook update site "(.*)" setting(site)
```

causes `site` to be set to `production` without using a pre block. As this is a regular expression, you can match anything, like either of two options:

```
select when webhook update site "(test|production)" setting(site)
```

will only match with site == test or site == production, and no other times, AND store the value in the site variable in the context of the rule.